# Getting to answer on difference quotient/function problem

Tags: functions

Q: Find the difference quotient $\dfrac{f(x) - f(3)}{x - 3}$ for $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$

Ans a: $\dfrac{1}{3x}$

Haven't been able to get to that answer. I got the bottom $3x$ right once but the top was still wrong, on the first thing I tried.

Comment: Hm, I think that should be $-1/3x$.

Comment: oops, yea, your right. Still, haven't gotten even that close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to be super slow and careful; I'm sure what I am doing is not different than what you did, just with some multiplication error removed, probably.

$$ \frac{f(x)-f(3)}{x-3} = \frac{\frac1x-\frac13}{x-3} = \frac{\frac{3}{3x}-\frac{x}{3x}}{x-3}$$
$$= \frac{3-x}{(3x)(x-3)} = \frac{1}{3x}\cdot\frac{-(x-3)}{x-3} = -\frac1{3x}$$

(Also doesn't help when the answer you're comparing to is wrong :P

Comment: Yea, I know, lol. Maybe I've been at this a little too long. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3}}{x-3}=\frac{3-x}{(3 x) \
(x-3)}=\frac{3-x}{3 x (x-3)}=-\frac{1}{3 x}$$